# Process training and test sets in GridSearchCV

Tags: scikit-learn, gridsearchcv

I want to evaluate different classifiers in performing the link-prediction task by using node embedding algorithms. More specifically, I want to evaluate if node embedding can improve the accuracy of different classifiers predicting new links between nodes.

My idea is the following:

- I create a dataset containing both positive and negative samples (real links and non-existing links)
- I split the dataset in Development Test (DS) and Evaluation Test (ES).
- I use the DS to perform the Grid Search cross-validation (CV) to find the best model
- I train the best model on the entire DS, and then I evaluate its performance on ES.

The problem is the following: I cannot use node embedding algorithms on the entire dataset because, in this case, ES will contain information related to the original graph topology. Therefore, I need to extract node embeddings from the training and test sets generated during the Grid Search CV, but how can I do it by using the `sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV` class?

Comment: You may want to create a custom transformer (there's an example in the [docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/compose/plot_column_transformer.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-compose-plot-column-transformer-py)) to perform the node embedding, then wrap that step in a pipeline with the rest of your model and pass that pipeline to `GridSearchCV`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I was checking the Pipeline class, but, as far as I understand, you can process the entire set used in the Grid Search (DS in my case), but you cannot distinguish between train and test sets generated during the CV. I need I kind of callback function called by the GridSearchCV when it has generated the training and test splits, so I can extract embedding from them separately.

Comment: I think you might still be able to use a custom transformer. You can give the transformer a member like `has_transformed`, and set that to true at the end of the  `transform` method. That way in the `transform` method, you know when you have a train set passed (`has_transformed == False`) and when you have a test set passed.